# Bootstrap Modal Only Displaying Part of Content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to create a modal to house content in it. It seems to only create one single page's worth of content though, and the rest of the content just falls out of the parent div.

[image]

Here's the html of the modal:

```
<div id="tr-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-dismiss">
                <button type="button" class="close closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-header profiler-header" id="headerView"><div>
                <div id="question-progress-bar"><div>
                <div class="progress active">
                    <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 16px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-modal-content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <div id="question-number"></div>
            <div id="progress-number"></div>
            <div id="question-title">
                <label class="control-label">From this list, which one best describes you?</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="question-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div data-fields="">
                    <div class="form-field-question-radio control-group form-field" data-field="">
                        <div id="tr-modal-radio-group" data-input="">
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-0" value="qx100-0">African American / Black
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-1" value="qx100-1">Asian / Asian American</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-2" value="qx100-2">Caucasian / White
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-3" value="qx100-3">Native American, Inuit or Aleut</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-4" value="qx100-8">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-5" value="qx100-7">Hispanic or Latino origin
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-6" value="qx100-4">Mixed Race
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-7" value="qx100-5">Other
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-8" value="qx100-6">Prefer not to Answer
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-0" value="qx100-0">African American / Black
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-1" value="qx100-1">Asian / Asian American</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-2" value="qx100-2">Caucasian / White
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-3" value="qx100-3">Native American, Inuit or Aleut</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-4" value="qx100-8">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-5" value="qx100-7">Hispanic or Latino origin
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-6" value="qx100-4">Mixed Race
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-7" value="qx100-5">Other
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-8" value="qx100-6">Prefer not to Answer
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="modal-table">
            <button id="modal-continue-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#modal-continue-button {
    color: #f6fcfc;
    background-color: #17b4b3;
}

.radio {
    border: 1px solid #777777 !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    margin: 0 .5em !important; 
}

.progress {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #d1f0f0;
    border-radius: 2em !important;
    width: 72%;
    margin: 24px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#bar {
    background-color: #17b4b3;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.progress.active .progress-bar, .progress-bar.active {
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}

.progress-bar {
    transition: 0.1s linear;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#question-progress-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

#tr-modal .modal-footer {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    height: 100%;
    /*display: table;*/
    width: 100%;
}

#tr-modal .modal-header {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .1;
    will-change: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;
    
}

.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0.65 !important;
    background-color: #555555;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.modal-dialog {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}
    
#tr-modal {
    text-align: center;
}

#tr-modal .closeModal {
    color: #666;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.closeModal:hover {
    color: #333;
}

#tr-modal #modal-continue-button {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.modal-dismiss, .modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-content, #tr-modal  {
    height: 100%;
}

.tr-modal-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#question-body .text-input {
    width: 210px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0.8em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    color: #777777;
}

.form-field-month .controls {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#tr-modal-radio-group .radio {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px !important;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #777777;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.tr-modal-content {
    max-width: 30em;
    margin: auto;
}
```

If the content isn't a large list that can fit completely on the page, it works great:
[image]

Any ideas how I can get the content to all display within the div container even if it requires scrolling? It seems to be stopping with the bottom of the `modal-dialog` despite it being set to having `height: 100%;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it in 2 ways.

> **1. Just add `overflow-x:auto` CSS property to `.modal-content`. It will add scroll for you.**

```css
#modal-continue-button {
    color: #f6fcfc;
    background-color: #17b4b3;
}

.radio {
    border: 1px solid #777777 !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    margin: 0 .5em !important; 
}

.progress {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #d1f0f0;
    border-radius: 2em !important;
    width: 72%;
    margin: 24px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#bar {
    background-color: #17b4b3;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.progress.active .progress-bar, .progress-bar.active {
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}

.progress-bar {
    transition: 0.1s linear;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#question-progress-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

#tr-modal .modal-footer {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    height: 100%;
    /*display: table;*/
    width: 100%;
}

#tr-modal .modal-header {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .1;
    will-change: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;

}

.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0.65 !important;
    background-color: #555555;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.modal-dialog {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}

#tr-modal {
    text-align: center;
}

#tr-modal .closeModal {
    color: #666;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.closeModal:hover {
    color: #333;
}

#tr-modal #modal-continue-button {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.modal-dismiss, .modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-content, #tr-modal  {
    height: 100%;
}

.tr-modal-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#question-body .text-input {
    width: 210px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0.8em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    color: #777777;
}

.form-field-month .controls {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#tr-modal-radio-group .radio {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px !important;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #777777;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.tr-modal-content {
    max-width: 30em;
    margin: auto;
}

.modal-content{
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#tr-modal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</button>

<div id="tr-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-dismiss">
                <button type="button" class="close closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-header profiler-header" id="headerView"><div>
                <div id="question-progress-bar"><div>
                <div class="progress active">
                    <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 16px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-modal-content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <div id="question-number"></div>
            <div id="progress-number"></div>
            <div id="question-title">
                <label class="control-label">From this list, which one best describes you?</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="question-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div data-fields="">
                    <div class="form-field-question-radio control-group form-field" data-field="">
                        <div id="tr-modal-radio-group" data-input="">
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-0" value="qx100-0">African American / Black
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-1" value="qx100-1">Asian / Asian American</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-2" value="qx100-2">Caucasian / White
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-3" value="qx100-3">Native American, Inuit or Aleut</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-4" value="qx100-8">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-5" value="qx100-7">Hispanic or Latino origin
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-6" value="qx100-4">Mixed Race
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-7" value="qx100-5">Other
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-8" value="qx100-6">Prefer not to Answer
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-0" value="qx100-0">African American / Black
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-1" value="qx100-1">Asian / Asian American</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-2" value="qx100-2">Caucasian / White
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-3" value="qx100-3">Native American, Inuit or Aleut</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-4" value="qx100-8">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-5" value="qx100-7">Hispanic or Latino origin
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-6" value="qx100-4">Mixed Race
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-7" value="qx100-5">Other
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-8" value="qx100-6">Prefer not to Answer
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="modal-table">
            <button id="modal-continue-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **2. You can just set height of `modal-content` to `auto` so that it
>       increases based on the content.**

```css
#modal-continue-button {
    color: #f6fcfc;
    background-color: #17b4b3;
}

.radio {
    border: 1px solid #777777 !important;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding-left: 35px !important;
    margin: 0 .5em !important; 
}

.progress {
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #d1f0f0;
    border-radius: 2em !important;
    width: 72%;
    margin: 24px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 400px;
}

#bar {
    background-color: #17b4b3;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    border-top-right-radius: 2em;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.progress.active .progress-bar, .progress-bar.active {
    -webkit-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    -o-animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
    animation: progress-bar-stripes 2s linear infinite;
}

.progress-bar {
    transition: 0.1s linear;
    float: left;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#question-progress-bar {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    z-index: 5;
    width: 100%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
    padding-left: 3em;
}

#tr-modal .modal-footer {
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 0em;
    padding-bottom: 0em;
    height: 100%;
    /*display: table;*/
    width: 100%;
}

#tr-modal .modal-header {
    padding: 0px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}

.modal-backdrop.in {
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    opacity: .1;
    will-change: opacity;
    transition-property: opacity;
    transition-duration: 0.3s;

}

.modal-backdrop, .modal-backdrop.fade.in {
    opacity: 0.65 !important;
    background-color: #555555;
    filter: alpha(opacity=70);
}

.modal-dialog {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0%;
}

#tr-modal {
    text-align: center;
}

#tr-modal .closeModal {
    color: #666;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

.closeModal:hover {
    color: #333;
}

#tr-modal #modal-continue-button {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.modal-dismiss, .modal-header, .modal-footer, .modal-content, #tr-modal  {
    height: 100%;
}

.tr-modal-content {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#question-body .text-input {
    width: 210px;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 0.8em;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-color: #dddddd;
    color: #777777;
}

.form-field-month .controls {
    padding-left: 0px;
}

#tr-modal-radio-group .radio {
    text-align: left;
    margin: 10px !important;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Montserrat-Regular, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: #777777;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.tr-modal-content {
    max-width: 30em;
    margin: auto;
}

.modal-content{
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-target="#tr-modal" data-toggle="modal">Open modal</button>

<div id="tr-modal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <div class="modal-dismiss">
                <button type="button" class="close closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                </button>
                <div class="modal-header profiler-header" id="headerView"><div>
                <div id="question-progress-bar"><div>
                <div class="progress active">
                    <div id="bar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 16px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tr-modal-content">
        <div class="content-container">
            <div id="question-number"></div>
            <div id="progress-number"></div>
            <div id="question-title">
                <label class="control-label">From this list, which one best describes you?</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="question-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal">
                <div data-fields="">
                    <div class="form-field-question-radio control-group form-field" data-field="">
                        <div id="tr-modal-radio-group" data-input="">
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-0" value="qx100-0">African American / Black
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-1" value="qx100-1">Asian / Asian American</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-2" value="qx100-2">Caucasian / White
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-3" value="qx100-3">Native American, Inuit or Aleut</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-4" value="qx100-8">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-5" value="qx100-7">Hispanic or Latino origin
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-6" value="qx100-4">Mixed Race
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-7" value="qx100-5">Other
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-8" value="qx100-6">Prefer not to Answer
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-0" value="qx100-0">African American / Black
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-1" value="qx100-1">Asian / Asian American</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-2" value="qx100-2">Caucasian / White
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-3" value="qx100-3">Native American, Inuit or Aleut</label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-4" value="qx100-8">Native Hawaiian or Pacific Islander
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-5" value="qx100-7">Hispanic or Latino origin
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-6" value="qx100-4">Mixed Race
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-7" value="qx100-5">Other
                            </label>
                            <label class="radio">
                                <input type="radio" name="field-input-question-radio" id="field-input-question-radio-8" value="qx100-6">Prefer not to Answer
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="modal-table">
            <button id="modal-continue-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You sir are amazing! Both worked but I think setting the height to auto works best (no extra white space at the bottom). Thanks for the thorough answer!

Comment: Anytime buddy.. Happy coding.. :)